# store same object reference with different values in map

Tags: java, collections

I have a requirement to insert same object reference with different values as below:

```
    Test.java:

        class Test {

            private List<String> elements = new ArrayList<String>();
        //add some elements and get

    public void add(String s) {
    this.elements.add(s);
    }

        public void clear() {
            this.elements.clear();
        }
        }

    Map<String, Test> map = new HashMap<String, test>();
    Test one = new Test();
  one.add("firstelement"); //adds to element list
    map.put("first", one);

    //clear and add some more elements
    one.clear();
    one.add("secondelement"); 
    //Add some more elements without creating 
    map.put("second", one);
```

Now, when in retrieval, as we are inserting same test reference in MAP, we have below output

Is there any way to resue existing Test object with different elements list in MAP??

```
map.get("first") //retrieving list with element "Second Element"
map.get("second") //retrieving list with element "Second Element"
```

Anyway to achieve this

Comment: This doesn't seem logical because you're fighting the language. When you `clear` the first one outside the map you're also clearing the one *inside* the map. All changes you make are reflected in both places so making a new list seems like the only logical way.

Answer (score 0):

You may want your `Map` defined as :

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
```

And change what you add to

```
one.add("firstelement");
map.put("first", one.get(0));
```

This will require a `get` method in `Test`:

```
 public String get(int index) {
        this.elements.get(index);
 }
```

***Edit***

If you want `Map` to store references to `Test` objects, use Sweeper's answer.

If you want `Map` to store to `List` objects, you can make a copy of that list before reusing `Test`: 
Add this method to `Test`:

```
private List<String> getList() {

    return this.elements;
}
```

and change the way you add to :

```
 Map<String, List> map = new HashMap<String, List>();
 Test one = new Test();
 one.add("firstelement"); //adds to element list
 //store a refrence to a copy of elements in map
 map.put("first",  new ArrayList<String>(one.getList()));
```

Comment: But if they clear `one` as in their example it doesn't much matter if you index into it. The values will be gone no?

Comment: `Map<String, String> ` does not store a reference to `one`  but to the String value of `one(index)`

Comment: Ah, I see what you're up to now. I suppose this is as good as they can get for what they want assuming they're not expecting a list of values.

Comment: I don't fully understand what the OP is trying to achieve. I added an option of storing the array list values before recreating `one`.

Comment: I'm assuming it's an X-Y problem since the description seems to "fly in the face of" Java's behavior.

Comment: Feedback would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

It isn't really clear in the question, but I guess you want to do this:

```
map.get("first") //retrieving list with element "firstelement"
map.get("second") //retrieving list with element "secondelement"
```

To do that, you must create another `Test` object. You should replace the line

```
one.clear();
```

with

```
one = new Test();
```

Comment: I have to reuse the existing object, not to create new object, everytime I need.

Comment: Then I don't think there is any way you can do that, except for the method shown in the other answer, which requires you to change the type of the map. @RamuPasupuleti

Comment: You can't re use it and expect it to hold values which has been cleared.

Comment: @RamuPasupuleti too bad.  There is no way to do both of those at the same time.